# Displaying image from array in Javascript in setTimeInterval method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, frontend

I am having little bit difficulty time pausing the image, so it gets rendered. I have images stored in even index in an `array` (for example: 2, 4, 6). And using `for loop`, I want to change the image every 2 seconds. On the load of the HTML page, I call `onLoad = executeOnLoad() in HTML`. The image changes from default to the image that is in sixth index, but after that it is not changing. It stays on that same index although, the console says the `i` is changing.

```
function executeOnLoad(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            console.log("started.."+i);
            displayImage(i);
        }

    }
}

function displayImage(i){
    console.log("displaying...." + i);
    document.getElementById("initial_image").src = contentArray[i];
}

window.setInterval("executeOnLoad()", 1000);
```

This is the console output that **repeats every 1 sec but image is not changing**:

```
started..0
displaying....0
started..2
displaying....2
started..4
displaying....4
started..6
displaying....6 < ---- The image here is displayed but, not changing to other..
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pause in your code. That loop just runs through all of your images and therefore only the last one will "stick".

You can fix this by using `settimeout`:

```
console.clear();
document.body.innerHTML = '';
//START
var contentArray = [
    'https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg',
    'https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/14/01/41/image-view-1139204_960_720.jpg',
    'https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/552738927_1280x720.jpg',
    'https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg',
    'https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/14/01/41/image-view-1139204_960_720.jpg',
    'https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/552738927_1280x720.jpg',
    'https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg',
    'https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/14/01/41/image-view-1139204_960_720.jpg',
    'https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/552738927_1280x720.jpg',
    'https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg',
    'https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/14/01/41/image-view-1139204_960_720.jpg',
    'https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/552738927_1280x720.jpg',
    'https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg',
    'https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/14/01/41/image-view-1139204_960_720.jpg',
    'https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/552738927_1280x720.jpg',
    'https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg',
    'https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/14/01/41/image-view-1139204_960_720.jpg',
    'https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/552738927_1280x720.jpg',
    'https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg',
    'https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/14/01/41/image-view-1139204_960_720.jpg',
    'https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/552738927_1280x720.jpg'
]

var initImg = document.createElement("img");
initImg.id = "initial_image";
initImg.src = '';
document.body.appendChild(initImg);

function executeOnLoad() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            (function (a) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log("started.." + a);
                    displayImage(a);
                }, 1000 * (a + 1))
            })(i);
        }

    }
}

function displayImage(i) {
    console.log("displaying...." + i, contentArray[i]);
    document.getElementById("initial_image").src = contentArray[i];
}

executeOnLoad();
```

Comment: Can you please explain why 1000 * (a + 1) is there?

Comment: @YogeshGhimire that `a` is a quirk of JavaScript. To make sure that i get a unique variable `i` I wrap my `setTimeout` in an anonymous function (`(function(uniqueVariable){})(loopVariable)`) and passes `i` which then becomes `a` in my new scope. I then set the timeout to fire in 1000 milliseconds (1 second) multiplied by the loop variable +1. that means that the first image will load in (1*1) second, the second image will load in (1*2) seconds, the third image in (1*3) seconds and so on. The `+1` is because the JavaScript loop start at 0 and i don't want to set at timeout to fire instantly.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a fiddle for you that shows even numbers.
I've used the `if` statement instead of the `for` loop you had because that would run all the loop in one go.

See it working here:

```js
var contentArray = ["0.png","1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png","5.png","6.png","7.png","8.png"]

var i = 0;
var numberOfImagesToDisplay = 6;
var speedOfAnimation = 1000;

function executeOnLoad(){
    if(i <= numberOfImagesToDisplay){
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            displayImage(i);
            i = i+2;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
        
    } else {
        i=0;
        displayImage(i);
    }
}

function displayImage(img){
    document.getElementById("initial_image").src = "http://www.marcelogil.com/fiddle/jsloop/" + contentArray[img];
}

window.setInterval("executeOnLoad()", speedOfAnimation);
```

```html
<img src="http://www.marcelogil.com/fiddle/jsloop/0.png" id="initial_image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

See this code, with some small changes. The interval does not have a loop inside it, but a single action. Each time the setInterval callback is called (i.e every one second) it goes one step further, until reaching the maximum desired length (which is 7, but should probably be `contentArray.length`) and then the interval clears itself. Clearing the interval is possible thanks to saving a refernce to it when declaring it (`var interval = window.setInterval(...)` and using the `clearInterval` method.

```
var i = 0, interval;

function executeOnLoad(){
    i++;
    if (i%2 == 0) {
        console.log("started.."+i);
        displayImage(i);
    }

    if (i >= 7) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}

function displayImage(i){
    console.log("displaying...." + i);
    document.getElementById("initial_image").src = contentArray[i];
}

interval = window.setInterval(executeOnLoad, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```js
var i = 0;
    var contentArray = [];
    contentArray.push('https://img.utdstc.com/icons/256/beautiful-life-quotes-android.png');
    contentArray.push('https://img.utdstc.com/icons/monospace-android.png');
    contentArray.push('https://img.utdstc.com/icons/cloud-print-android.png');
    contentArray.push('https://img.utdstc.com/icons/120/desire-the-game-for-couples-android.png');
    
    function displayImage(){
        console.log("displaying...." + i);
        if(i < ((contentArray.length) - 1)){
         i++;
        }else{
         i = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById("initial_image").src = contentArray[i];
        window.setTimeout( displayImage, 4000);
    }
    
     displayImage();
```

```html
<img id="initial_image"/>
```

See [a working example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4z5npm2t/18/)

Comment: Thanks. It is creative.

Comment: Once you liked, you could mark my answer as helpful,  to help me with my reputation in StackOverflow? Thanks!